# Помогите реализовать задание в cmd

Tags: cmd

Не получается реализовать данное задание, вот мой пример кода, но он не работает, подскажите как выйти из этой ситуации или источники где можно почитать о реализации такого задания.Заранее спасибо
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
set type
set /p name=vvedite imya file 
dir /b %name%.*

if "%name%.*" == ".txt"(
"type" = text
echo %name%.txt
goto sss
pause)
elseif 
"%name%" == .cmd(
"type" = command
goto sss)
elseif 
"%name%" == .com(
"type" = program
goto sss)
elseif 
"%name%" == ""(
"type" = none
goto sss)


if not exist %name%.* (
echo file %name% не существует
pause)
else (
echo name %name% type %type%
pause)


pause >nul
```

Comment: Лучше перевести задание на русский язык, не все учасники сообщества знают украинский. И сам вопрос сформировать лучше по-конкретнее (*помогите реализовать* - это не о чём, если честно. Такая информация, как правило,  указывается в теле вопроса)

Comment: А какое вообще задание? Что вообще надо сделать?)

Answer (score 0):

### Рабочий код

```
@echo off
::: Аргументы вызова:
::: 1. (обязательный) имя каталога поиска
::: 2. (опциональный) chars
:::     указывает на необходимость вывести характеристики файла

::: Вводим имя для поиска - без расширения
set /p name=Enter file name: 

::: Проверяем существование файла с указанным именем и 
::: различными расширениями в указанном каталоге
if not exist %1/%name%.* (
    echo file %name%.* does not exist in %1 folder
    goto exit
)

::: Определяем имя и расширение файла при помощи команды dir,
::: Получаем ее вывод при помощи команды for /f и анализируем
::: '~' модификаторами параметра цикла
for /F %%a in ('dir /b %1\%name%.*') do (
    set filename=%%~nxa
    set fileext=%%~xa
)

::: Проверяем расширения и определяем тип файла
for %%a in (.txt .doc .docx) do (
    if %fileext% == %%a (
        set type=text
        goto sss
    )
)

for %%a in (.com .exe) do (
    if %fileext% == %%a (
        set type=program
        goto sss
    )
)

for %%a in (.cmd .bat) do (
    if %fileext% == %%a (
        set type=script
        goto sss
    )
)

for %%a in (.bmp .gif .jpg .png) do (
    if %fileext% == %%a (
        set type=picture
        goto sss
    )
)

set type=unknown

::: Выводим информацию о файле
:sss
    echo File %filename% is %type%

::: Если был задан второй аргумент: chars, то выводим характеристики файла
if _%2 == _chars (
    dir %1\%name%.* | findstr %filename%
)

:exit
pause >nul
```

### Варианты запуска и выводимые результаты:

---

Cуществующий файл

```
C:\Projects\StackOverflow>test.cmd .
Enter file name: a
File a.txt is text
```

---

Cуществующий файл с выводом характеристик

```
C:\Projects\StackOverflow>test.cmd . chars
Enter file name: a
File a.txt is text
03/28/2019  02:21 AM                11 a.txt
```

---

Существующий файл неизвестного типа

```
C:\Projects\StackOverflow>test.cmd .
Enter file name: test
File test.py is unknown
```

---

Несуществующий файл

```
C:\Projects\StackOverflow>test.cmd .
Enter file name: b
file b.* does not exist in . folder
```

---

По командным файлам есть хороший сайт [ss64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)

Comment: даю знать: нужны разъяснения :-)

Comment: @Grundy, извиняйте, уважаемый. Не так уж много тут трюков. Надо ж оставить вопрошающему возможность немножко самообразоваться. Вот, разберет работающий пример - и будет польза человеку. А мне спать давно пора. Это у вас там утро, а у нас тут ночь. :)

Comment: Вам действительно нужны разъяснения? Или код сам себя объясняет? Если что-то неясно - не стесняйтесь - справшивайте. Я отвечу. Good night

Comment: Конечно нужны. С ходу и не поймешь чем код в вопросе отличается от кода в ответе. Стоит добавить эту информацию и пояснения почему именно так нужно делать.